# Octave Error: surface: rows (Z) must be the same as length (Y) and columns (Z) must be the same as length (X)

Tags: octave, mesh

Octave shows this error when trying to mesh a matrix:

> error: surface: rows (Z) must be the same as length (Y) and columns (Z) must be the same as length (X)*

```
N =

        0        0   0.0057
   1.0000        0   0.0165
   1.0000   1.0000   0.0145
        0   1.0000   0.0038
   0.5000   0.5000        0
   0.6667   0.5000   0.0001
   0.3333   0.5000   0.4560
   0.6443   0.5833   0.8280
   0.5833   0.6443   0.5774
   0.5000   0.6667   0.0000
   0.4167   0.6443   0.0001
   0.3557   0.5833   0.5898
   0.3557   0.4167   0.6540
   0.4167   0.3557   0.6016
   0.5000   0.3333   0.0000
   0.5833   0.3557   0.0001
   0.6443   0.4167   0.7667
   0.5000   0.2083   0.1617
   0.2083   0.5000   0.1576
   0.5000   0.7917   0.0048
   0.7917   0.5000   1.0050
   0.2961   0.7039   1.0004
   0.7039   0.2961   1.0027
   0.7039   0.7039   1.0024
   0.2961   0.2961   1.0008

tx= N(:,1);
ty= N(:,2);
tz= N(:,3);

length(tx);
length(ty);
length(tz);

figure(1)
[x,y] = meshgrid (tx, ty);
mesh(tx,ty,tz);
xlabel ("tx");
ylabel ("ty");
zlabel ("tz");
```

I am trying to mesh the matrix `N` using `mesh` but it keeps showing up the above error. I've already checked the size of X, Y and Z using the command `length` and it they all are the exact same size. So I don't understand what is the reason behind the error.

Also I have tried changing the command `mesh(tx,ty,tz)` to `mesh(x,y,tz)` but it is still the same.

Pd: I used the reference page from Octave to learn about the mesh command in this link: https://docs.octave.org/v6.2.0/Three_002dDimensional-Plots.html and also checked the code for the mesh of the example given.

Thanks in advance if someone can answer me.

Comment: Is `N` the heights you want to plot?

Comment: If you read the error message more closely, you’ll see that `mesh` wants its Z to be a 25x25 matrix, not a 25x1 vector.

Comment: The Z coordinate in N is the height i want to plot, and the X Y columns in N are the intervals X and Y to be used in the plot

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't have a surface here, but a (x,y) irregular scatter with the z values on it. You need first to interpolate your available z values onto on regular (x,y) grid: for this, you can use the `griddata` function:

```
N =[
        0        0   0.0057
   1.0000        0   0.0165
   1.0000   1.0000   0.0145
        0   1.0000   0.0038
   0.5000   0.5000        0
   0.6667   0.5000   0.0001
   0.3333   0.5000   0.4560
   0.6443   0.5833   0.8280
   0.5833   0.6443   0.5774
   0.5000   0.6667   0.0000
   0.4167   0.6443   0.0001
   0.3557   0.5833   0.5898
   0.3557   0.4167   0.6540
   0.4167   0.3557   0.6016
   0.5000   0.3333   0.0000
   0.5833   0.3557   0.0001
   0.6443   0.4167   0.7667
   0.5000   0.2083   0.1617
   0.2083   0.5000   0.1576
   0.5000   0.7917   0.0048
   0.7917   0.5000   1.0050
   0.2961   0.7039   1.0004
   0.7039   0.2961   1.0027
   0.7039   0.7039   1.0024
   0.2961   0.2961   1.0008]

tx= N(:,1);
ty= N(:,2);
tz= N(:,3);

txi = linspace(0,1,101);
tyi = linspace(0,1,101);
[x,y] = meshgrid (txi, tyi);
z =  griddata (tx, ty, tz, x, y)

figure(1)
mesh(x,y,z);
xlabel ("tx");
ylabel ("ty");
zlabel ("tz");
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `plot3` to directly plot your scatter in in the (x,y,z) space. But floating points in a 3D space are difficult to visualize, so it can help for instance plotting also some bars from the (x,y) plane to each point:

```
figure(2)
plot3(tx,ty,tz,'o')
hold on
for k = 1:length(tx)
    plot3([tx(k) tx(k)],[ty(k) ty(k)],[0 tz(k)],'b')
endfor
hold off
xlabel ("tx");
ylabel ("ty");
zlabel ("tz");
```

[image]

Comment: I understand the need of creating a regular (x,y) grid, however is there a possibility of using the X and Y columns from N as the X Y intervals to do the mesh and the Z column from N to be the height of the plot?  The main reason is that, in the problem i am trying to solve, the Z column represents the value in each point from a triangulation done in the software gmsh, and the X Y columns in N are the coordinates from each node in the triangulation.

Comment: @Pablo. What you want is not clear to me... If you want to plot a kind of triangulation, a list of points is not enough, it misses how they relate to each others to form triangles.

Comment: Sorry. i didn't explain myself well. The N matrix is a coordinates matrix in which the first two columns are the X and Y coordinates from a triangulation that i previously did in GMSH.  The third column represents the value for the solution of the problem of distribution of electric potential solved using Galerkin Method. I want to plot this using de first column from N as the X interval and the second one as the Y interval, and the height of it are the third column from N that correspond to each X Y value from N.  Please let me know if i explained it clear, if not i'll open a new question

Comment: @Pablo What do you mean by "X interval" and "Y interval" ?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot about this post, i finally solved it when i asked my teacher about it, i was using the wrong command. The command that does what i intended to is trisurf. This way i don't require a regular mesh to plot it. Thanks for the help!